# Is ampersand followed by int.MaxValue rounding down?

Tags: c#, integer, ampersand

I have a piece of C# code that another developer has copied from a blog post which is used to encode/obfuscate an integer. this code contains some syntax that i am unfamiliar with. It looks like it might be rounding down the result of the calculation to prevent it from exceeding the maximum size of an integer, if that is the case i am worried that two input values could potentially result in the same output. The obfuscated values need to be unique so i'm worried about using this code without understanding how it works

this is a simplified version of the code:

```
public static int DecodeNumber(int input)
{
    return (input * PrimeInverse) & int.MaxValue;
}
```

so my question is 
**what is the meaning of the ampersand in this context and will this code produce an output that is unique to the input?**

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/and-operator

Comment: @HansPassant that's not true, negatives are represented in two-complement, just flipping sign bit is not enough to turn negative to (corresponding) positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no "rounding" going on here. This is a sneaky way of truncating the most significant bit when multiplication results in overflow.

According to the documentation, `int.MaxValue` is 2,147,483,647, which is `0x7FFFFFFF` in hex. Performing a bitwise AND with this value simply clears out the most significant bit.

Since the intention of the code is to use `int.MaxValue` for its binary pattern, rather than for its numeric value of the highest `int` that could be represented by `Int32`, I would recommend either using `0x7FFFFFFF` constant explicitly, or computing it with `~` expressionL

```
return (input * PrimeInverse) & ~(1 << 31);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I haven't dealt with bitwise operations before so I'm still struggling to understand if this code will give me the results i need. Specifically i need to be sure that it is not possible for different inputs to result in the same output. Is that possible with the code i posted?

Comment: @dotcentric-samb Since one bit of information gets discarded in this operation, it is guaranteed that for each possible output there are exactly two inputs that produce it. -2147483647 and 1 is one such pair. [See this demo](https://ideone.com/9uuvNu) to see how it works in practice.

Comment: thanks for the clarification and for the demo, this is exactly what i needed to know.

Answer (score 2):

The ampersand is a bitwise AND operator. The numbers on the sides of this operator will be considered in binary format and a logic AND would be performed on the bits of the same significance.
The `int.MaxValue` equals 2,147,483,647. The result of this operation is explained as below:

operation:

```
a = x & int.MaxValue;
```

result:

```
if (x >= 0) {a = x;}
if (x < 0) {a = x + 2,147,483,648;}
```

if x is non-negative then a = x;

if x is negative, then a = x + 2,147,483,648;

***EDIT :***

*Logical Operations:*

Logical operations like `AND`, `OR`, `XOR`, etc are defined to work on Boolean (logical) values. Boolean variables can have either `1` or `0` as their values. The result of `AND` operation between two logical variables will be `1` if and only if both the variables are equal to `1`. This is shown below:

```
0 & 0 = 0  
0 & 1 = 0  
1 & 0 = 0  
1 & 1 = 1
```

Bitwise AND operator on numbers works using the basic `AND` operator. First the two numbers on the sides of operator are converted to binary format. If the number of digits in both numbers are not equal, zeros are added to the left side of the number with less number of digits to have the same number of digits for both numbers. Then the digits of the same significance are `AND`ed one by one the way explained above and the result of each operation will be written on the place with the same significance constructing the result. The bitwise and between `12` and `7` is shown below. `12` is demonstrated as `1100` in binary format and `7` is `0111`.

```
12 = 0b1100    

7  = 0b0111    

12 & 7 = ?    

1 1 0 0 &    
0 1 1 1
----------  
0 1 0 0 = 4
```

Comment: thanks for this, you have made it really clear. I'm going to have to read up on bitwise operations a bit more i think.

Comment: you're welcome @dotcentric-samb . I am glad it helped.
About the bitwise operations, I will edit the answer adding a brief explanation on it. It is really simple to learn and use.