# Understand strange code found in ReadOnlyMemory<T>

Tags: c#, .net, performance, disassembly

I looked with IL disassembler into the code of the Length property of the ReadOnlyMemory struct (.NET 461) and found this strange code:

```
public int Length => this._length & int.MaxValue;
```

what is the reason of AND-ing with int.MaxValue here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is ampersand followed by int.MaxValue rounding down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48831713/is-ampersand-followed-by-int-maxvalue-rounding-down)

Comment: @Charlieface I don't think it's a dupe - what matters is _why_ the authors of `ReadOnlyMemory<T>`  felt the need to specifically truncate `_length` - implying they're using the 31st bit for _something_...

Comment: It's just knocking out the most significant bit, which normally represents the negative sign. By the way the original source code is here https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/ReadOnlyMemory.cs

Comment: @Dai Maybe, but the source code doesn't seem to bring anything up. Might be a check for a torn read in 32-bit, can't see anything else.

Comment: @Charlieface You linked to answer, and it's not a sign-bit: _"The highest order bit of _index is used to discern whether _object is a pre-pinned array."_

Comment: @Dai Actually the code got changed some years ago so it doesn't even do the above anymore, Git blame here https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/commit/47aa264f8fddf26c3afffe5259fca539e795be2c

Comment: @Charlieface JFYI the original code now does not have `public int Length => _length;`.

Comment: I posted prematurely - I confused `_index` with `_length`, derp.

Comment: The actual source does *not* contain this. I suspect this is an artifact of the disassembler or IL compiler. Perhaps the compiler is packing 2 32-bit values into a single 64-bit word

Comment: @Charlieface Yes but that's .NET Core / .NET 5+ - the OP is asking about .NET 4..X

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I see the `internal const int RemoveFlagsBitMask = int.MaxValue;` field in the current NuGet package binaries for `System.Memory` for .NET Framework (for .NET 4.6.1+). Presumably .NET Framework and .NET Core+ will always have entirely different implementations because .NET Fx 4 doesn't support `Span<T>` natively?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos blame has something similar - [soruce](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blame/33b8804c6646d37a4693f9d757a9a61dc8e3635d/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/ReadOnlyMemory.cs) `public int Length => _length & RemoveFlagsBitMask;` where `private const int RemoveFlagsBitMask = 0x7FFFFFFF;`, possibly package/.NET 4.6.1 version was not updated for some time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimers:

- This answer concerns both the original design of `Memory<T>` (i.e. how it was prior to its redesign in 2018) - and its layout in the builds of [the current latest version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Memory/4.5.5#dependencies-body-tab) of `System.Memory.dll` **for .NET Framework 4.x specifically** *and not* the far more recent versions that ship with .NET 5+ - *not that they're significant*, though - they aren't).
- <sub>(As a disclaimer on *style*: I see the authors of `Memory<T>` chose to use underscore prefixes for instance state field names - which is not something I would ever do myself - I'm just using their field-names verbatim for clarity)</sub>
- Note that both `Memory<T>` and `ReadOnlyMemory<T>` have identical layouts - the only difference is in their exposed interface design so I'm using the terms `ReadOnlyMemory<T>` and `Memory<T>` interchangeably here.

---

- The `Memory<T>` type is a `struct` type that needs to be lightweight, which means it can't have any more fields than absolutely necessary:

  1. It needs a pointer (strictly speaking, an *object-reference*) to the actual memory target, such as the byte-array buffer or whathaveyou.

     - In `Memory<T>` this is represented by an opaque `Object` field named `_object`, as it can represent not just a `Byte[]`, but also a `Char[]` or  `String` or *any other type* that `Span<T>` can work with.
  2. It needs an `Int32 _length` field to store the length of the memory-area/buffer that it's pointing to.

     - .NET has [a practical limit of 2GiB per object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/gcallowverylargeobjects-element?redirectedfrom=MSDN#:%7E:text=On%2064%2Dbit%20platforms%2C%20enables%20arrays%20that%20are%20greater%20than%202%20gigabytes%20(GB)%20in%20total%20size.), so there's no point making this `Int64` either (and doing so would make `Memory<T>` consume 2x more storage).
     - And incidentally, a range of 0-2GiB only requires **31 bits** to represent, not 32.
  3. It also needs an `Int32 index` field to store its current read/write "head" *into*
- So that means `Memory<T>` (if *packed* in-memory) already consumes `32 + 32 + 32 = 96 bytes` on x86, or `64 + 32 + 32 = 128 bytes` on x64 - which is pushing at the limit for how big a `struct` can become.
- *But that's not all*: `Memory<T>` needs 2 more pices of information:

  1. It needs to store information about the *type* of memory that `_object` points to so it can dereference it correctly, otherwise it will need to rely on (very expensive) runtime type-tests (e.g. the `is` operator) before it can safely performing *any* action, which would be ruinous for performance. (This is because the actual low-level operations for getting data out of a `Byte[]` is different to a `Byte*` - or a `Char[]` vs. a `String`).
  2. It also needs to know if `_object` is a reference to a *pinned-memory object* - as that tells it if [it needs to `Pin()` the memory before](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/copying-and-pinning) it can be used safely or if it can skip that step.
- So that's two more separate `bool` fields to store - fortunately boolean values are simple 2-state values that can be represented by a single bit in-memory (whereas the `System.Boolean` (`bool` in C#)  type uses a whole 8-bits - and *four bytes* when marshalled to a Win32 `BOOL` value).
- Given that `Memory<T>` is already using 2x 32-bit integers for `_index` and `_length` already and both of those fields will only ever hold a 31-bit value - it means there's *2 unused bits right there for the taking*: - so it *sneakily appropriates* the MSBs of `_length` and `_index` to store that "is pinned-memory or not" and "is-.NET-array-or-not" state.

---

In 2018, some point after `System.Memory` was first released for .NET Core - and also made available for .NET Framework 4.x users - the design of `Memory<T>` was changed to no-longer require two bit-fields (as type-information about the `_object` can be carried "*for free*" within the type-system). Here's the diff, where we can see the old and new versions side-by-side, with their respective explanatory comments about both designs:

[*Quoeth the source*](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/fb700b3f31d9114493c56b2a5d8b98d75a21c87a/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/ReadOnlyMemory.cs#L26C12-L26C101):

> ```
> // The highest order bit of _index is used to discern whether _object is an array/string or an owned memory
> // if (_index >> 31) == 1, object _object is an MemoryManager<T>
> // else, object _object is a T[] or a string.
> //     if (_length >> 31) == 1, _object is a pre-pinned array, so Pin() will not allocate a new GCHandle
> //     else, Pin() needs to allocate a new GCHandle to pin the object.
> // It can only be a string if the Memory<T> was created by
> // using unsafe / marshaling code to reinterpret a ReadOnlyMemory<char> wrapped around a string as
> // a Memory<T>.
> ```

In this diff, they implemented the change to reduce this down to just using `_index` for the "is-pinned-or-not" state thus leaving `_length` alone. I speculate that because `_length` is accessed more than `_index` it made sense to use `_index` to store the flag-bit instead of `_length`.

---

Unfortunately I'm not able to get the *exact* source for the .NET Framework port of `System.Memory` (if it even exists). The assembly metadata for our `System.Memory.dll` `v.4.5.5` says it's `[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("4.6.31308.01 @BuiltBy: cloudtest-841353dfc000000 @Branch: release/2.1-MSRC @SrcCode: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/32b491939fbd125f304031c35038b1e14b4e3958")]` - [but no such commit exists in the public `corefx` repo](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/32b491939fbd125f304031c35038b1e14b4e3958).